# How to convert multidimensional array to simple array using values as a keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How to convert multidimensional array from the example below

```
Array

(

    [0] => Array

        (

            [cf] => Juan

            [nf] => 5

        )

    [1] => Array

        (

            [cf] => Kyu

            [nf] => 10

        )

)
```

to an simple array using values as keys and values where [cf] is a key and [nf] is value

```
Array
(
"Juan"=>"5",
"Kyu"=>"10"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(
  0 => array(
      'cf' => 'Juan',
      'nf' => 5
    ),
  1 => array(
      'cf' => 'Kyu',
      'nf' => 10
    )
);

$result = array();

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $result[$value['cf']] = $value['nf'];
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like ..

```
<?php
$arr = array( 0 => array( "cf" => "Juan", "nf" => 5, ),1 => array(  "cf" => "Kyu", "nf" => 10, ),);

foreach ($arr as $arr1)
{
    foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v)
    {
        $arrnew[]=$v; // Adding just the values to the temp array
    }
    $new_arr[$arrnew[0]]=$arrnew[1]; //Your new array gets those values from the temp array
    unset($arrnew); //Deleting your temp array
}

print_r($new_arr); //Printing the results
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [Juan] => 5
    [Kyu] => 10
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$a = array(array('cf'=>'joan', 'nf'=>'5'), array('cf'=>'lol', 'nf'=>'55'));
$new = array();

foreach( $a as $k ) {
    $new[$k[cf]] = $k[nf];
}
print_r( $new )
```

http://codepad.org/xVbcDXLD

Answer (score 0):

```
$x=array(
    0=>array(
        "cf"=>"Juan",
        "nf" => 5,
    ),
    1=>array(
        "cf"=>"Kyu",
        "nf" => 10,
    ),
);

foreach($x as $k=>$v) $result[$v["cf"]]=$v["nf"];

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you iterate through it, and build up your array, like this:

```
$mysimplearray = array();
foreach($originalarray as $id => $innerarray) {
   $mysimplearray[$innerarray["cf"]] = $innerarray["nf"];
}
```

voila, your data is stored now as a simple 1 dimension array, in $simplearray.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have your function:

```
$array =
array (
    0 => Array
        (
            'cf' => 'Juan',
            'nf' => 5
        ),
    1 => Array
        (
            'cf' => 'Kyu',
            'nf' => 10
        )
);

$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $value => $new_array_elem) {
    $key = $new_array_elem['cf'];
    $value = $new_array_elem['nf'];
    $new_array["$key"] = $value;
}

print_r($new_array);
```